# Test code with validation rules

Tags: unit-test

I apologize for this rookie question.

I have a post update trigger which will create a new record if a certain field is checked on a record. It was running fine. However, now that I have added new validation rules the test code for it is no longer running properly. The validation checks the contents of the parent record of the current record. If a certain field is blank on the parent record the validation rule will prompt the user to change the parent record's value, and will therefore not proceed with the trigger.

I have added a line to the test code which will give a value to that parent record but the test code still errors out when it is run. Here is the test code :

```
@isTest
private class testProjectInitiationTrigger {

    static testMethod void ProjectInitiationTriggerTest() {

        Account account = TestHelper.createAccount();
        Opportunity objOpp = TestHelper.createOpp(account);

        //this is the parent record being created
        Country_by_Country__c objC = TestHelper.createCBC(objOpp);
        objC.Current_Tvl_Mgmt_Supplier__c = 'Test Supplier';

        //this is the child record which the trigger will run off
        Project_Initiation_del__c oPI = new Project_Initiation_del__c();
        oPI.Name =  objC.Name;
        oPI.Country_by_Country__c = objC.Id;
        oPI.BCD_Travel_Business_Owner__c = objC.CreatedById;
        oPI.CDS_Product_s_Sold__c = 'Product A';
        insert oPI;

        //this is the child record field which will initiate the post update trigger
        oPI.Initiate_Implementation__c = true;
        update oPI;
    }
}
```

The field which is in question is Current_Tvl_Mgmt_Supplier__c. I'm populating it with "Test Supplier" but the Validation Rule which checks to see if it is blank is still causing this test code to fail.

Does anybody know what I can do to satisfy the Validation Rule in this test code ?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You changed the value in memory, but you didn't commit the change to the database, so the validation rule doesn't see it:

```
    //this is the parent record being created
    Country_by_Country__c objC = TestHelper.createCBC(objOpp);
    objC.Current_Tvl_Mgmt_Supplier__c = 'Test Supplier';
    update objC;  //  <<< ADD THIS LINE
```

Add the line commented above to commit the change.

Comment: You're welcome, @Zoom_v.  If this helped you, please mark my answer as accepted (check mark icon).  Thanks!

Comment: fwiw - I had intended to do that. I was required to wait at least 5 min after your answer to mark it. I'm just coming back here now.  :-)  Thanks again.